# What will be power spectral density?

Tags: fourier-analysis

If the autocorrelation of a random process is given as 
$$r_x(k) =  \begin{cases} 10 - \vert k \vert &\mbox{if } |k| < 10 \\
0& \mbox{else.} \end{cases} $$ 
What will be the DTFT of this random process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
R\left(\omega\right) & =\sum_{k=-9}^{9}\left(10-\left|k\right|\right)e^{-ik\omega}=\left(\frac{\sin\left(5\omega\right)}{\sin\left(\omega/2\right)}\right)^{2}
\end{align*}